# .htaccess rewriteCond part of the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

URL applying rule(s):

```
https://olddomain.ch/de/qahmkitd73/
https://olddomain.ch/fr/qahmkitd73/ 
https://olddomain.ch/en/qahmkitd73/ 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} chezcamillebloch\.ch$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/.*\/qahmkitd73\/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://newdomain.ch/$1/qahmkitd73 [NE,R=301,L]
```

this should redirect to `https://newdomain.ch/**/qahmkitd73`
the `**` should be dynamic from the URL (de/ or en/ or fr/)

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your .htaccess rules file in following manner. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```bash
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.ch$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.ch/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> this should redirect to `https://newdomain.ch/**/qahmkitd73` the `**` should be dynamic from the URL `(de/ or en/ or fr/)`

You may use this redirect rule:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.ch$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de)/qahmkitd73/?$ http://newdomain.ch%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```